# Event handling in Ruby

Tags: ruby, events, event-handling

i want to be able to do event handling with ruby. I know there is no native way to do this, but i found a solution here in stackoverflow:

```
class EventBase
    def initialize
        @listeners = Hash.new
    end

    def listen_event(name, *func, &p)
        if p
            (@listeners[name] ||= Array.new) << p
        else
            (@listeners[name] ||= Array.new) << func[0]
        end
    end

    def ignore_event(name, func)
        return if !@listeners.has_key?(name)
        @listeners[name].delete_if { |o| o == func }
    end

    def trigger_event(name, *args)
        return if !@listeners.has_key?(name)
        @listeners[name].each { |f| f.call(*args) }
    end
end


class MyClass < EventBase
    def raise_event1(*args)
        trigger_event(:event1, *args)
    end

    def raise_event2(*args)
        trigger_event(:event2, *args)
    end
end

class TestListener
    def initialize(source)
        source.listen_event(:event1, method(:event1_arrival))
        source.listen_event(:event2) do |*a|
            puts "event 2 arrival, args #{a}"
        end
    end

    def event1_arrival(*a)
        puts "Event 1 arrived, args #{a}"
    end
end
```

The problem is this:
1- It seems when you add a method to the listen array it executes right away
2- When the event triggers, it throws a NoMethodError: undefined method call for nil:NilClass

I am new to ruby so i dont understand the code completly, i feel its missing some pieces of code lol... (mostly because i dont know all ruby syntax) 
thanks

Some questions:
- What means &p ?
- What is ||=?
- what means <

Comment: Somoe of the post was cutted out:
-What means <<?
-What means |f| and |o| o ?

Comment: Or maybe im not calling listen_event correctly?
for example, i am doing
listen_event(:indexChanged,sayIndex(:index))

sayIndex(index) being the method previously defined.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be trying to reinvent the wheel here.  I would recommend using [`Observable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/observer/rdoc/index.html) instead.  It's in the standard library, just `require "observer"` and `include` the `Observable` module into your class.

Comment: yeah ive seen it, the problem is that it only allows you to observe one "event" (the status of the class). I want to be able to handle multiple events in one class

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do event handling in a small Ruby script (ie: NOT a web application), then I recommend using the **Unobservable** gem (as in: it's NOT the Observable gem, har har har).  You can find some basic details / links about the gem here:

https://briandamaged.org/blog/?p=1074

https://briandamaged.org/blog/?p=1161

This gem makes it easy to define multiple events in a single object.  For example:

```
require 'unobservable'

class Button
  include Unobservable::Support

  attr_event :clicked
  attr_event :double_clicked

  def click(x, y)
    raise_event(:clicked, x, y)
  end

  def double_click(x, y)
    raise_event(:double_clicked, x, y)
  end
end

button  = Button.new
button.clicked.register {|x, y| puts "You just clicked: #{x} #{y}"}

button.click(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lol, ok i solved the problem... i wasnt calling listen_event correctly...

it should be 
listen_event(:indexChanged,method(:sayIndex))
not 
listen_event(:indexChanged,sayIndex(:index))

still learnin the ropes on ruby lol

Comment: Yes. I think I asked the original question. You just need to give the pointer to the event handler function (i think `listen_event(:indexChanged, :sayIndex` should work too)